# Android ble device issue with rssi and connectivity

Tags: android, bluetooth-low-energy

I am working on android ble using nordic. I have few issues:

1. I see rssi strength of device in dBm like -88 dBm, -77dBm which value is good for proper working as it is in negative so bit confusing to me.
2. How can I restrict show that my code will show only my ble devices not other.

Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Negative values of dBm are simply less than 0 dBm. Look it up on Google.

Comment: i mean to say -66 dBm is better or -77 dBm

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding the details of the part you are using, e.g. the Ble module you are using. A link to the datasheet would be even more helpful.

Comment: -66 dBm is higher power than -77 dBm.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. > I see rssi strength of device in dBm like -88 dBm, -77dBm which value is good for proper working as it is in negative so bit confusing to me.

Question: *"..which value is good for proper working?"*
Answer: *It depends.*
For example, this [nordic semiconductor BLE SoC: nRF52825](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.nrf52.v1.0.0%2Fchips%2Fnrf52832.html) claims to have a TX power of the range -20 dBm to +4 dBm in 4 dB steps.

Or, the configuration guide for a [BlueGiga module: BLE112](https://www.bluegiga.com/protectedstore/8pHYFByrRbCfvauWLt5CMQ/Nt7TtF09HSQiUwxXa0Tjtw/DvRzOCaL9e0RrYYm5MTz-AcntfXrRWlreZr56XILUrcrR-fGgVSr/Bluetooth_Smart_Software_v1.3.1_API_Reference.pdf) claims to have the range from -103 to -38 in dBm. (I have used this module extensively and it does what it claims). Interesting but irrelevant fact is that, the radio used for BLE112 is a nordic semiconductor based chip.

To sum it up, I would recommend you to read datasheets, user guides and other support documents, and the forums for getting the information on the range of rssi values.

---

2. > How can I restrict show that my code will show only my ble devices not other?

I am not sure if this is quite on-topic here at electronics.stackexchange.com, But, here you go.

Answer: Assuming that you want your app to connect only to a particular set of device that has some unique identification. Say for example, a BLE-enabled digital pen configured by you should only connect to your app and no other device gadget should be able to connect with your app. If that is the use case and if you have the liberty to configure the GATT server on the BLE device then you can add some custom characteristics in GAP service on GATT server which will be unique to those devices, and known to the android application. Needless to say, you will have to [generate a 128-bit custom UUID](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/) for that characteristics and the UUID will be known to your application as well. This is more like a work-around solution.

This paragraph above is taken as is from [my own answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120063/4228131).